# Getting started with Chat-clients/rooms in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, chat, desktop-application, livechat

I'd like to add a very basic chat-room to my application (.NET 3.5 winforms desktop app) so users can ask questions and talk together without using a browser or email or chat client. I want to make it free-for-all, i.e. no sign-ins or registration required, the fact that you're running my software is good enough. Unfortunately I'm out of my comfort zone here and I don't really know where to start. Can I use Google Talk for this or does that require a GMail account for every user? Do I need to supply my own server or something? Is there a solution that requires minimum coding on my part? Would that solution allow me to transfer binary data as well as text?

Anything to get me started really, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do using WCF. Check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx) about writing a peer-to-peer chat client using WCF.